# Angular 2 and Typescript - Importing multiple interfaces from a single file

Tags: angular, angular-cli, typescript2.0

I've tried searching high and low for an answer to this but hopefully someone will be able to answer this quickly.

I have a Angular 2 app and I'm using Typescript interfaces to help structure various bits of data.  The issue is that I have one file with multiple interfaces and when I try to import that into a component, the first interface can be referenced without problems, but the second one causes an error.

For example ...

```
myapp.model.ts
  export interface IObjectA { id: number; name: string; }
  export interface IObjectB { id: number; related: IObjectA[]; }

myapp.component.ts
  import { IObjectB } from './myapp.model';
```

This results in the Angular CLI compiler to fail with the error ...

```
... myapp.model.ts is not a module ...
```

I can't seem to work out how to solve this one.  I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious, but you know what they say about a second pair of eyes.

Comment: please checkout your path to myapp.model.ts, it's seem your path is wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems this issue was caused by a problem with my angular cli compiler (the one that is started with NG SERVE).  Once I stopped and restarted NG SERVE, the issue went away.  I could have multiple interfaces in one file and successfully import them into my components.

For everyone's information, I'm running (ng -v) ...

- Angular 4.0.1
- @angular/cli 1.0.0
- Node 7.5.0
- Typescript 2.2.2

Hopefully that helps...

Comment: I can confirm that. ng 4, ts 2.2 cli 1.0.1

Comment: Observed similar behavior, needed to restart ng serve for multiple interfaces exported from single file to work

Answer (score 3):

Make your interfaces in each separate file. I.e make `objectA.ts` and `objectB.ts` I think this is a bug in angular-cli. If you want to dig deeper take a look at [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2034)

Comment: I discourage anybody from that approach. Export / import of multiple interfaces from single .ts file is a standard practice & should not be dropped when faced with bug exposed by an external tool. 

@Dazfl Provided a correct way to resolve this temporary Angular cli compiler bug. You just need to restart "ng serve" process.

Comment: @Fill thanks for letting me know. I thought that multiple interfaces should have their own separate files, adhering to Single Responsibility Principle. Anyways, I would just have to research about this.

Comment: to be fair it all comes to the specifics of the project & fetish of leads but an interface that spans across less than few lines as a rule of thumbs would treat it as a supportive one that makes more mess in the filesystem than helps.

Kudos for mentioning SRP! Downvote was to promote best suitable answer for the question. In any other scenario probably would lean towards your answer.

Comment: Same as @brijmcq, we place interfaces into their own separate files, e.g. `product.interface.ts` following SRP principle in a feature based organization. Much easier to locate and maintain.

Comment: @demisx glad to know that somebody else have the same file structure. It may add more files but it pays off in a long run especially if you are working with a team

Comment: I am learning angular and some tutorials that I have seen are using Single responsibility principle. I think using this principle will help when you are working in a team for better code readability and will make your code organized, structured and separated in correct classes

Comment: @davecar21 glad to know you are doing it this way too! You may never know how big your application will get especially in an enterprise setting